# Can this sum of squares be negative?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

I must be tired, but could you please point to me what I am missing here:

$$
(\cos a + \cos b)^2 + (\sin a + \sin b)^2 = 2\cos a\cos b + 2\sin a\sin b = 2\cos(a-b)
$$

Clearly the left hand side is non-negative, but the simplification leads to something that can be negative. I feel like it is staring me in the face, but I can't see it; am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing $+2$ on the right side of your equality.

Comment: That would explain it.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also the "middle" part as written (we know it's missing the +2) equals $2\cos(a-b)$.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks for catching that too, I think it's time to sleep for me!